# For regex, r'[!-\.&]' what does it mean?

Tags: python, regex

Is it !-\ (characters from 33=ord('!') to 92=ord('\')
and '.' and '&' in a set?

I think my interpretation is incorrect based on my test.

But python reference doesn't say anything wrong with my interpretation.
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `r'[!-\.&]'` is just a complicated form of writing `r'[!-.]'`.

It matches all characters with `ord` between `33 = ord('!')` and `46 = ord('.')`, i.e. any of the following:

```
!"#$%&\'()*+,-.
```

The escaping backslash before `.` is ignored in character classes; it is unnecessary (`.` matching all characters in a character class wouldn't make any sense). Since the ampersand `&` is already in the character class, it is superfluous as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Precisely. Copied your comment into the answer.

Comment: @Eugene Yup. `Character class` is the formal name of `a set of characters` or `the stuff in brackets`.

Comment: An escaping backslash is not ignored in a bracketed character class. For example, it must be used to prefix a literal backslash if a backslash should be part of the class. It would be correct to say the backslash is optional before '.' because '.' loses its special meaning in a bracketed character class.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the intention of this regex is to match any character between "!" and "." (notice that the slash is escaping the "." character), which are `! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , -` . (from the Unicode table at http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html).

Two comments about the expression:

1. Usually, you don't need to escape characters within brackets `[]` (except, maybe, by the `\` itself).
2. The ampersand symbol "`&`" is already contained in the range defined by "`!-.`", so it is redundant.

Comment: 1) There are other characters that need to be escaped, eg: `-[]^`, depending on where you put them 2) I think it's possible that the character class was meant to match `!-.&` only, ie: `-` is not meant to use to denote a range, but the hyphen itself.

Answer (score 2):

Tests may show that the pattern matches `chr(33)` through `chr(46)`, but the pattern is not guaranteed to work that way on all systems. Here's why. Character sets vary from system to system.

This is why the Perl regex documentation specifically recommends “to use only ranges that begin from and end at either alphabetics of equal case (`[a-e]`, `[A-E]`), or digits (`[0-9]`). Anything else is unsafe.” (Perl regex is relevant because that's the regex used by Python.)

So, if this pattern is ever run on an EBCDIC based platform, it will match a different set of characters. It is only correct to say that the pattern matches `chr(33)` through `chr(46)` on ASCII based platforms.

Comment: Does your warning apply to UTF-8/16?

Comment: @Eugene: It is very perilous to use *any* regexes on bytestrings encoded in *any* multibyte encoding. Decode them to unicode first.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash escapes the dot and the range will thus be from `!` to `.`. The regex will match:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-.
```

The last `&` is not necessary since it's included in the range, and escaping a dot is not needed either since it's inside a character class.